# Dynamically add layout on button click and get text from the layout?

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, android-edittext, viewgroup

So I have a layout that gets added to the main layout every time the user presses a button.  I got that working fine, but that layout happens to consist of several EditTexts.  What would be the best way to get the text from the EditText?  I only have the id of the layout itself, not the EditTexts inside the layout.

I thought of just adding EditTexts dynamically one by one, but is there a more efficient way of doing it?  I'd much rather just inflate an xml layout every the button is clicked.

Comment: How many EditTexts? Is there limits?

Comment: there are 2 EditTexts and 2 TextViews in the layout that gets inflated.  The TextViews don't matter.  The user can add as many layouts as they want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're adding new views by inflating them and then adding them to the main view similar to below.

```
LinearLayout newView = (LinearLayout)this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);

LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
mainView.addView(newView);
```

You can use findViewById() on the newView to access each EditText as required.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) newView.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
String text = editText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for some reason I didn't realize that I could just get the ids one by one and give them a different reference.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a fixed layout you inflate from a particular XML file, you can also use getChildAt(int index) to find a particular view of the ViewGroup.